# React Native Expo 41 app crashing on debug remotejs enabling

Tags: react-native, debugging

I am new to react-native and having the following issue.When I run app without enabling remotejs dubug option from my device, it works fine.But as soon as I enable the debug remotejs after shaking the device, app crashes wit the following error in the console and the app crashes.

```
(node:1064) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1
```

- Expo: 41.0.1
- react: 16.13.1
- react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding C:\Windows\System32\ to path variable then restarting computer.